# What's the reason we 'have to' change the SSH port just after installation?

Tags: ssh

In every tutorial I got from internet, it is always said that *You could change your port number in /etc/ssh/ss....* What's the reason behind this? Why do we have to change the port just after the installation in our OS?

I just read through the [official SSH page](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/port) but I still can't  figure out why this would be necessary.

Comment: Because otherwise [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1256917/how-to-protect-agains-milions-failed-login-attempts) could happen. Millions of bots trying to guess your root password within just a few days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Have to" - no. It's *worth* doing, though. While SSH's port is standard, there's no real downside to using a non standard port (outside of needing to remember what port you used).

It's a "relatively cheap" way to ward off the simplest attempts to get into your system - by bots checking for SSH at a standard port, and then testing usernames and passwords in brute force attacks.

*However*, it is, practically speaking, security by obscurity. Turning off SSH as root (which is always a good idea) and setting up key based authentication (which makes guessing your password impossible) is going to do much more, but changing ports is a simple painless first step.

Comment: The last paragraph is particularly important -- changing the port number is great for cutting down the number of casual attacks that hit your SSH service, but does basically nothing to stop a serious attacker. I think of it as putting up a sign that says "[You must be at least as tall as this sign to attack the computer](https://www.cardcow.com/429730/notice-you-must-tall-this-sign-attack-city-far-side-cartoons/)".